# Box-shadow not working as expected

Tags: css

I found this nice box-shadow example on: http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects.

I want to apply effect number 2 on a website template that I am building however if I use the code from example 2 anywhere in the site it works fine but as soon as I put it inside the header the shadow doesn't come up anymore:

```
<header class="header_w clearfix">
    <section>

        <div class="logo_w">
            <h2>Logo</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="box2 effect2"></div> // suppose to get the shadow effect but not

    </section>

    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Nav element</li>
            <li>Nav element</li>
            <li>Nav element</li>
            <li>Nav element</li>
            <li>Nav element</li>
            <li>Nav element</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</header>
```

Full code here:http://jsfiddle.net/3NDMB/1/

tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems

The header_2 class in the header states white background, that makes the shadow hard to see.

And your box2 class has a height too high, that also makes the shadow invisible. I changed it to 80 px.

The result:

[http://jsfiddle.net/vals/3NDMB/2/]